# Is there more efficient way to to find maximum pairwise hamming distance in an array of hashes then brute force O(N^2) algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, information-theory

We have unsorted array of hashes, each hash is a 64bit integer.
We need to find the pairwise hamming distance in an array. What state the problem to find maximum Manhattan distance between points in 64Bit space where each dimension has only 0 and 1 state.

The simplest solution is:

- just pick each item one-by-one
- and compare (find the hamming distance) with the rest items starting for this one.

> That gives us $O(N^2)$ complexity, where $N$ is length of list. But can we do better because of nature of Hamming distance and nature of 64bit numbers? Could we use binary operations here?

Comment: Hamming distance satisfies the triangle inequality $d(a,b)+d(b,c) \ge d(a,c)$. You can use this to skip some computations if all you need is the biggest Hamming distance of any pair. Note sure whether this is enough to get below $O(N^2)$ and what a good algorithm using that fact would look like.

Comment: Do you need it exactly? Can you live with decent bounds on it? For instance, it is $O(N)$ to compute the ($\mathbb{F}_2$) mean, and then to find the node furthest from this. Twice this distance gives you a $2$-approximation.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 wouldn't a $2-$ approximate solution be useless if it outputs an guess $\geq n/2$?

Comment: I mean because the max distance is very likely quite close to $n=64$ the bitlength.

Comment: @kodlu I mean then its a little obvious that you would report 64 as the upper bound. Really it depends on the application, although I agree that for fixed string-lengths a $2$-approximation would be kinda weak. In any case, my question really was trying to get at if approximate solutions could be acceptable, and how good they'd need to be. Essentially since bringing in some randomised algorithm might get to some decent approximation at $o(N^2).$

Comment: @stochasticboy321, sorry I didn't mean this to be so harsh, and you're right.

Comment: @kodlu Oh, I didn't find that harsh at all, no worries :)

Comment: Related (for the minimum distance) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829839/finding-the-minimum-hamming-distance-in-less-than-on2m-time

Comment: For values in $\{0,1\}^d$ where $d=64$, the hamming distance will equate to the $L_1$ norm. Thus we are looking for is an $L_1$ diameter. Due to the particularity of this norm it is possible to use the embedding tricks to arrive at an efficient algorithm linear in $N$ (exponential in $d$). For large $N$ and small $d$ this algorithm will be beneficial. I have provided the details and an implementation at another stack-exchange post:
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28583/approximation-diameter-2-dimensional-space

In your case $2^d$ is quite large, but I though you'd want to know.